# how to make a refresh button using javascript

Tags: javascript, refresh, browser-refresh

Can I make a function to refresh the page using JavaScript (same browser refresh button)

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this by using: `window.location.reload()`

Answer (score 20):

google? : javascript refresh

```
<!-- Codes by Quackit.com -->
<a href="javascript:location.reload(true)">Refresh this page</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I added a refresh button in a form I made.

```js
<script>
  function refresh(){
        window.location.reload("Refresh")
      }
</script>
```

and then called it via button in html:

```
<p><input type="button" value="Refresh" onClick="refresh(this)"></p>
```